# ssh: Could not resolve hostname (Docker, gitlab-ce)

Tags: git, ssh, docker, gitlab-ce

I have set up docker toolbox and installed gitlab-ce to test the gitlab continuous integration feature, I was able to connect to the gitlab instance and create a repository, created a new ssh key and pasted it on the repository.
But the problem is when I am trying to push to this repository it's giving me this error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname c52795c5acda: Name or service not
>   known
>       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>       Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>       and the repository exists

The git url is the following :

```
git@c52795c5acda:root/my-project.git
```

I replaced **c52795c5acda** with the container ip address and port, and seems to be working with HTTPS but not with ssh.
My system is windows 8.1, and I'm running the docker on a virtual machine. Can anyone point out the issue?

Comment: How exactly are you starting the image? Can you show your `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @Matthew Thank you for your response. I am completely new to dockers. 
I am running the gitlab-ce from Kitematic. I am not using any command to start it.

Comment: I don't know much about kitematic, but you need to find the ports and start from there. Maybe start [here](https://docs.docker.com/kitematic/userguide/#/list-the-exposed-ports-and-how-to-access-them).

Answer (score 1):

The name `c52795c5acd` is the random hostname that docker has given your container. It's likely to change, as is the IP address.

The simplest solution is to map a port from your docker host to your docker container with the `-p` option. Then you can use your docker host name in your git urls.

You also need to configure your external URL for gitlab, see here: http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html